# Fastest way to get list<string> of words from string

Tags: c#, string, list, optimization

```
string [] words= text.Split(punctuation);
List<string> WORDS = words.ToList();
```

According to Stopwatch() it takes about 0,009 ms. Can i make this code faster?

Comment: Why would you want it to be faster? It already seems pretty fast to me?

Comment: this is a loaded question that will spew opinions... and may cause WWIII.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
Yourlist.addrange(source.split(...))
```

Comment: `new List(source.Split`... will be even faster. `AddRange` calls `InsertRange` which [allocates a temporary array for copying](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/79de3e39e69a4811.html)

Comment: Thanks for your Feedback!